# Lista encadeada dentro de Lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou com dificuldades com listas encadeadas dentro de uma lista encadeada.
O programa é um jogo de cartas em que existe uma lista duplamente encadeada de jogadores e dentro de cada nó dessa lista, uma lista (a mão) de cartas.
Não estou conseguindo adicionar uma carta à lista de cartas. Como acessar corretamente o nó do jogador e como acessar a primeira posição da lista dentro deste nó?

Minhas structs:

```
typedef struct Carta{
    int valor;
    char naipe;
}Carta;

typedef struct Cartas{
    Carta Item;
    struct Cartas *Prox_carta;
    struct Cartas *Primeiro, *Ultimo;
    int Tamanho_Mao;
}Cartas;

typedef struct Jogador {
    int id_jogador;
    Cartas *Primeira_mao;
    struct Jogador *Prox, *Ant;
    struct Jogador *Prim_Jogador, *Ult_Jogador;
    int Tamanho;
}Jogador;
```

A função para tentar adicionar cartas:

```
int Adiciona_Carta(Jogador *jogadores, Cartas *mao, int x, Carta carta){

    Jogador *aux;
    Cartas *novaCarta, *aux2;
    novaCarta = (Cartas*)malloc(sizeof(Cartas));
    novaCarta->Prox_carta = NULL;
    novaCarta->Item.naipe = carta.naipe;
    novaCarta->Item.valor = carta.valor;
    aux = jogadores->Prim_Jogador;

    while (jogadores->id_jogador != x){
        aux = aux->Prox;
    }
    aux2 = aux->Primeira_mao;
    mao->Primeiro = aux->Primeira_mao;
    if (aux->Primeira_mao == NULL){
        Cria_Mao_Carta(mao);
        mao->Primeiro = novaCarta;
        mao->Tamanho_Mao++;
    } 
    if (carta.valor > aux2->Item.valor){
        novaCarta->Prox_carta = mao->Primeiro;
        mao->Primeiro = novaCarta;
        mao->Tamanho_Mao++;
    }
    for (aux2 ;; aux2 = aux2->Prox_carta){
        if(carta.valor > aux2->Prox_carta->Item.valor){
            novaCarta->Prox_carta = aux2->Prox_carta;
            aux2->Prox_carta = novaCarta;
            mao->Tamanho_Mao++;
        }
        if(aux2->Prox_carta == NULL){
            aux2->Prox_carta = novaCarta;
            novaCarta->Prox_carta = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me ajuda
**https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412245/lista-encadeada-socorro**

Comment: me ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412245/lista-encadeada-socorro

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo, antes de tudo, criar uma estrutura separada pra lista.

```
typedef struct Conteudo{
int valor;
char naipe;
}Conteudo; 

typedef struct Cartas{
    Conteudo Item;
    struct Cartas *Prox_carta;
}Carta;

typedef struct ListaCartas {
    carta *primeiro, *ultimo;
    int tamanho;
}
```

faz o mesmo esquema com os jogadores, fica muito mais claro que que ce tá fazendo. ficou bastante confusa sua estrutura desse jeito.

e pelo amor de deus, não fica usando aux pra tudo não, dá um nome pra variável que outra pessoa que estiver lendo seu código vá entender =/

não dá pra entender seu código da função sem saber pra onde o aux do tipoJogador foi parar, ce não especificou que que a função Cria_mao_carta faz